# I cannot get my submission for the UVA challenge "3n+1" to be accepted. All I keep getting is runtime error. What can I fix?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

No matter what I change or what I try do I cannot make my code work. I think it has to do with the formatting of the way the UVA java submissions are unclear. I have tried removing the "public" on all the methods, changing the exceptions that Main throws, changing how the while loop in the beginning works but nothing seems to. What else can I do?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            if(line.equals(""))
                System.exit(0);
            String[] temp = line.split(" ");

            int i = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
            int cycle = findCycle(i, j);

            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + cycle);

        }
    }

    public static int findCycle(int i, int j){
        int sentNum = i;
        int cycles = 0;
        while(sentNum <= j){
            int n = cycle(sentNum);
            if(n > cycles){
                cycles = n;
            }
            sentNum++;
        }
        return cycles;

    }

   public static int cycle(int i){
        int count = 0;

        while(true){
            count++;
            if(i == 1)
                return count;
            else if(i % 2 == 1)
                i = 3*i + 1;
            else
                i = i/2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the 'throws' from the main method. You could just apply the normal debugging technique of starting with the minimum possible code (an empty main), and see if that compiles, then add more code bit by bit until the problem occurs, then you'll find out what the problem is. This technique is much faster than what you're doing, which is basically guessing.

Answer (score 4):

Did you even *read*  the FAQ about submitting Java solutions?

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=30

I quote:

> Do not use public classes: even Main must be non public to avoid
>   compile error.

Comment: I've changed that multiple times, still doesn't work. And it's not a compile error, it's a runtime error.

Comment: @user Well, your question says that you removed the `public` from the methods, it doesn't say anything about the class. Anyways, in that case I guess it's because you hardcoded `" "` as the separator of the numbers, if there's a tab instead of a blank in the input, your program fails with an NFE.